# How to show a specific column in 50 databases?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 50 databases in mysql, there is an one specific column called ***product_number*** in all of them(***databases and tables***),but ***the name of the tables are different***, is there anyway to select or show them all?
as you know better than me in each database and table I can easily show them with this command :

```
SELECT product_number
FROM 'products'
LIMIT 50
```

but what about the others ?
for example :

```
use * 
SELECT product_number
FROM *
```

how is it possible ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why you have 50 db?

Comment: @inetphantom, I have 50 portal that generates our products with a specific number and everyday I have to check some of them , I'm just wondering is there anyway to do it quickly ?

Comment: Maybe you can use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS table in the databases and find the tables with the product_number column

Comment: I can not think of another way than semi-hardcoding, i just do not see why your data architect made 50 tables.

Comment: as @AgeDeO said: select from INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS, save them into an array/internal table, iterate through it and do your buissness logic in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the tables containing the `product_number` column by accessing the `information_schema` tables:

```
SELECT c.`TABLE_SCHEMA`, 
  c.`TABLE_NAME`, 
  c.`COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` c
  WHERE c.`COLUMN_NAME` = 'product_name'
```

Comment: Thnx but it just show me the structure I want the data of 'product_name' !

Comment: You pass the data returned to a `PREPARE` statement and execute it

Comment: Hm, actually it is not possible, the way MySQL handles the prepared statements prevents you from binding a table name to a variable. You would have to retrieve the list of schema/tables as provided by my query, and then use something different than SQL to loop over it.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You just need to fiddle around with string concatenation a little.

Comment: See this answer of mine for example of how can this be done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430865/how-to-preload-tables-into-innodb-buffer-pool-with-mysql

Comment: @A Hocevar, Thnx for your help ! 1++